# how to fix these errors in centos7

Tags: linux, centos7

I'm running this command

```
./start-gui.sh in centos7
```

these errors  occur how to fix that

> ./monero-wallet-gui: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by ./mone   ro-wallet-gui)
>   ./monero-wallet-gui: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by ./mo   nero-wallet-gui)
>   ./monero-wallet-gui: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by ./mone   ro-wallet-gui)
>   ./monero-wallet-gui: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./mo   nero-wallet-gui)
>   ./monero-wallet-gui: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /root/   monero-wallet-gui/libs/libicui18n.so.55)
>   ./monero-wallet-gui: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /root/   monero-wallet-gui/libs/libicuuc.so.55)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Probably just need to install `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like missing library. Have you tried YUM or [RPM Find](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libstdc%2B%2B.so.6)? If yes, check the path and where your app is searching.